# Which of the following languages is accepted by this Pushdown Automaton?

Tags: pushdown-automata

This is a question from a past paper. I am struggling to get my head around the concept of a PDA. I understand that it is a Finite Automaton with a stack but am stuck as far as answering questions like this one. Thanks.

[image: PDA Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is a, $\{a^n b^{2n} | n > 0\}$.

First, the machine pushes $a$'s onto the stack until the first $b$. Then, for every two $b$'s in the string, it pops off one $a$. Then, if the machine is at the end of the string and the stack is empty, it accepts.

If the stack of $a$'s runs out while the machine is still popping pairs of $b$'s or there are $a$'s left in the stack when the last $b$ is popped, then the machine rejects.

> I am struggling to get my head around the concept of a PDA.

Notation varies, but in the diagram you provided, I think `nop` means "read the thing on top of the stack and leave it there" and `pop` means "read and remove the thing on top of the stack".

For more info, you could read the chapter on PDA's in Michael Sipser's book *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*.

Answer (score 0):

the ans is C
push all a's and pop each a for each b, if the stack is empty when all b's are scanned. Then this CFG.

Comment: Have you read the other answer? It seems to contradict yours.